# Pandas - need to do multiple split operations on filename to create df with Ticker and Exchange for import to SQL

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following file:

H:\EOD_DATA_RECENT\DOWNLOADS\SPLIT_ADJUSTED\STC.V_2021-11-08.csv

where the first part of the name  before the first period is the Ticker symbol ( STC )
the part after the period but before the _ is the Exchange ( V )

The columns in this file have only Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume

I am able to successfully use the commands below (in particular the line with the split operation) to create another column called "Ticker" based on the splitting of the
filename. I can then create the total_df at the end and eventually push to SQL and the new column is there with the proper ticker.
I need to be able to also split out the exchange by doing the same thing. In order to do that I have so somehow specify the part of the filename
after the first period, before the underscore. Not sure if both operations can be done in the same line, or do I need to specify a different dataframe
with the other split operation?
Thanks alot

here is the code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

files = glob.glob("H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\DOWNLOADS\\SPLIT_ADJUSTED\\*.csv")

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp).assign(Ticker=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in 
files])

Ticker = df['Ticker']
#Exchange = df['Exchange']
Date = df['Date']
Open = df['Open']
High = df['High']
Low = df['Low']
Close = df['Close']
Volume = df['Volume']

total_df = pd.concat([Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume],
                 axis=1, keys=['Ticker','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])
```

Comment: you should be able to add a second assignment in the same statement. see last example here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

Comment: Thanks, I was able to combine two together like this but still not giving the correct result because now the Exchange is everything to the left of the underscore in the filename. I need a way to get just the part between the first period and the underscore. : df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp).assign(Ticker=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0], Exchange=os.path.basename(fp).split('_')[0]) for fp in files])

Answer (score 0):

Assuming filenames like `CELZ.US_2021-11-10.csv`, to do multiple splits, you can create each column by:

1. splitting once at first period in the filename
2. splitting at the underscore in the filename

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(fp).assign(
        Ticker=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0],
        Exchange=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[1].split('_')[0]
    ) for fp in files
])
```